# How to respond to annotation button press with Storyboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, storyboard, mkannotationview

I have the right button on an annotation as follows:

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
rightButton.tag = [annotation index];

[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationViewClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

In my annotationViewClick method I would normally navigate to the detail view controller by using 'initWithNibName' and pushViewController

How do I do this when I am using storyboards? I guess I need a segue?
Somebody give me a push in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In storyboard, through Inspector window, you give the destination view controller an identifier (name), e.g. `LocationDetailControllerIdentifier`
2. In the method that gets fired by tapping the callout accessory of annotation view:

> ```
> LocationDetailController *ldc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationDetailControllerIdentifier"];
> // do further customization if needed
> ldc.title = @"Title";
> ...
> //assuming you are using UINavigationController
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:ldc animated:YES];
> ```

-

Comment: Apple recommends against this: "However, if you do instantiate a view controller programmatically, you do not get any of the behavior of a segue. To display the view controller, you must implement additional code. For this reason, you should rely on segues where possible and use this technique only when needed." (from the [VC guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW5)) See `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: I read it. It is not against it. The example that follows in the link you provided, follows the same logic.

Comment: I used this and got the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Define a segue by dragging in IB from the source view controller (the view controller itself, not any control within it) to the destination view controller. Give it an identifier in the inspector.

Now, you can programmatically perform that segue from anywhere you like (say, your `annotationViewClick:` method) with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" sender:self]`. (Note that said method doesn't give you access to the destination view controller, so you might still want to implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` for configuring it based on which annotation was tapped.)

Comment: "based on which annotation was tapped" — Yeah, that's precisely the part that I'm missing. How do I get which annotation was tapped?

Comment: Ok, I passed it through the `sender:` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is for a `MKMapView`?

You can't add annotations in storyboarding for an `MKMapView`. You'll have to do it in the code of your `MKMapViewDelegate`, in this method:

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```